# Can we nest many do-until loops together using just one do in octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

I have several conditions to be satisfied so as the code to run properly. So, can I use many until . For example, I have a code that uses for loop to compute several matrices. But, my further code requires the matrices computed to be seperately invertible.
Code:

```
n=4;
p=3;
% x1=a[4 x3] vector
%gamma(:,:,i) is some [4x 4] matrix
for i=1:n
    do
      v_k=blkdiag(eye(n-i),gamma(:,:,i),eye(i-1);
    bar_B=v_k(1:p,:);
    bar_A=v_k(p+1:n+p,:);
    until (det(bar_A)!=0)
    x1=inv(eye(n)-bar_A);
    until (det((x1*bar_B))!=0)
endfor;
```

Any ideas. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Can't you just join your two conditions using `&&` operator?

Comment: @m7913d ok, thanks, I got it. But, what about the case when my conditions are several steps apart, say in the above example, I need to put  three more steps in between first until and second until in order to calculate x1 vector.

Comment: You can replace the first `until` with a conditional `break`.

Comment: @m7913d ok, thanks. So then, I need to keep using breaks whenever I need to use a conditional, isnt it? By the way, you said replacing the until with a break. Then, the syntax would be do something; break(condition1); break(condition2);until (condition3). Is it right?

Comment: I think `break(condition)` is not legal, you should write `if (condition) break; end`

Comment: @m7913d thanks. so then, just the do and the last until should remain and all others should be replaced by 'if (condition) break; endif;'. Am I right in that?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Just give it a try and you will see if it works

Comment: I find when setting up complicated loops and conditions, it is useful to make a very simple example first. Something like a simple incremental counter, and then step through using debug program controls (brreakpoints, `keyboard`, `dbstep`, `dbcont`, or the GUI equivalents) to make sure it moves through the conditional sections correctly.  Good luck.